# cocoa : assign nstimeInterval value to nsdate?

Tags: cocoa

I want to assign nstimeInterval value to nsdate.

```
  NSDate *startTime=[NSDate date] ;
  NSDate *endTime=[NSDate date] ;
   NSTimeInterval difference=[endTime 
   timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];

    startTime=difference; This gives me an error.
```

how can i assign my difference result of nsTimeInterval type to nsdate?

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `NSTimeInterval` is the *difference* between two dates.  What you're trying to do is like telling the program to:

> Set the date to 2 days.

When what you want to do is tell the program to:

> Set the date to last monday plus 2 days.

Therefore you need to use one of these family of `NSDate` methods:

```
+ dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:
+ dateWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:
+ dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
+ dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
– initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:
– initWithTimeInterval:sinceDate:
– initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
– initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:
```

Where you create the `NSDate` with some reference date plus/minus the `NSTimeInterval`; note that `NSDate` objects are *immutable* so there are no methods to change the date represented by the object using `NSTimeInterval` values.

See the [`NSDate` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.

To correct your code, this is how you'd do it:

```
NSDate *startTime=[NSDate date] ;
NSDate *endTime=[NSDate date] ;
NSTimeInterval difference=[endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:startTime];
NSDate *newTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:difference sinceDate:startDate];
```